# Why my xlabels are outside the chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, zoo

I'm trying to make a chart in R using ggplot and the xlabels shows outside the chart.

follow the code:

```
#packages
library('readxl')
library('gridExtra')
library('scales')
library('ggplot2')
library('ggrepel')
library('zoo') 
library('ggpubr') 
#Reading data
dados <- read_excel("~/teste_dash.xlsx")
#transforming 'dados' as date
dados$Data<-as.yearmon(dados$Data)
cpl<-ggplot(dados, aes(x=Data,y = CPL))+
      ggtitle(label = "",subtitle = "CPL")+
      geom_point(aes(color=Origem),size=3,show.legend = F)+
      geom_line(aes(color=Origem),size=2,show.legend = F)+
      labs(y="",x="")+
      scale_color_manual(values = c("#1c4587", "#6d9eeb"))+
      theme_classic()+theme(axis.text.x= element_text(face = 'bold',colour = 'grey'),
      axis.line.x = element_line(colour = 'grey'),
      axis.ticks.x = element_line(colour='grey'),
      axis.text.y= element_text(face = 'bold',colour = 'grey'),
      axis.line.y = element_line(colour = 'grey'),
      axis.ticks.y = element_line(colour='grey'),
      plot.subtitle = element_text(colour = "#1c4587",face = 'bold'),
      legend.position = "top",legend.title = element_text(face = "bold",size = 12),
      legend.text =element_text( size=10))+
      scale_x_yearmon(format = '%b-%y',n=12 )
```

When I run the chart show like this with the x-labels  outside the chart:

[image: Chart with x-labels outside]

I have no idea what is wrong, because the 'Jul-17' isn't in my previously data.

My data

```
structure(list(Origem = c("Example 1", "Example 1", "Example 1", 
"Example 1", "Example 1", "Example 1", "Example 1", "Example 1", 
"Example 1", "Example 1", "Example 1", "Example 1", "Example 2", 
"Example 2", "Example 2", "Example 2", "Example 2", "Example 2", 
"Example 2", "Example 2", "Example 2", "Example 2", "Example 2", 
"Example 2"), Data = structure(c(1532044800, 1529452800, 1526774400, 
1524182400, 1521504000, 1519084800, 1516406400, 1513728000, 1511136000, 
1508457600, 1505865600, 1503187200, 1532044800, 1529452800, 1526774400, 
1524182400, 1521504000, 1519084800, 1516406400, 1513728000, 1511136000, 
1508457600, 1505865600, 1503187200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), CPL = c(23.11, 19.87, 17.96, 16.86, 14.44, 
11.26, 14.58, 22.24, 19.5, 19.34, 18, 14.95, 39.43, 40.96, 43.07, 
49.01, 36.53, 29.79, 24.06, 19.53, 48.46, 46.52, 43.86, 39.49
)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the `scale_x_yearmon()` which is messing up for me in `ggplot2 3.0.0` - it seems to be doing strange things to the `panel.grid` resulting in an uneven spread of dates across the axis. I cannot fix that but I can suggest a different approach.

Instead of transforming your date column into `yearmon` instead convert into `Date`:

```
dados$Data<-as.Date(dados$Data)
```

or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dados <- dados %>% mutate(Data = as.Date(Data))
```

next plot as you did before with `scale_x_date`:

```
library(scales)

ggplot(dados, aes(x=Data,y = CPL))+
  ggtitle(label = "",subtitle = "CPL")+
  geom_point(aes(color=Origem),size=3,show.legend = F)+
  geom_line(aes(color=Origem),size=2,show.legend = F)+
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format('%b %y'))+
  labs(y="",x="")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#1c4587", "#6d9eeb"))+
  theme_classic()+theme(axis.text.x= element_text(face = 'bold',colour = 'grey'),
                        axis.line.x = element_line(colour = 'grey'),
                        axis.ticks.x = element_line(colour='grey'),
                        axis.text.y= element_text(face = 'bold',colour = 'grey'),
                        axis.line.y = element_line(colour = 'grey'),
                        axis.ticks.y = element_line(colour='grey'),
                        plot.subtitle = element_text(colour = "#1c4587",face = 'bold'),
                        legend.position = "top",legend.title = element_text(face = "bold",size = 12),
                        legend.text =element_text( size=10))
```

[image]

## update:

you can put 12 months on the chart fairly easily using `scale_x_date`. One way is to use the `scales` package and `pretty_breaks(12)`:

```
scale_x_date(labels = date_format('%b %y'),breaks = pretty_breaks(12))
```

This plots the dates at the *exact* date on which the data is at. If you wanted to plot the data by just the month and year of the data point, a workaround would be to format your data with:

```
dados$Data <- as.Date(as.yearmon(dados$Data))
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer. I'm gonna stop using 'scale_x_yearmon()' and I will figure out how to put 12 months using something else.

Comment: see my updated answer - you can still put 12 months on with `scale_x_date`

Comment: Another thing I can not get is 'Oct-17' is not in the right place. I mean, it must be below the second circle. I had use the 'scale_x_date()' as well, but because this I put the 'scale_x_yearmon()' to try resolve this issue.

Comment: @JoãoPedroPires the data point will only be on `Oct-17` if your data is on `01-Oct-17`. The second datapoint is at `20-Aug-17` for example1 and `20-Sep-17` for example2. It is plotting them on the exact date.

Comment: now I understand how this chart works, thanks very much helped a lot.

Comment: @JoãoPedroPires if you want all points to be plotted by month only, ignoring the day, a workaround would be: `dados$Data <- as.Date(as.yearmon(dados$Data))`

Comment: That's what I want. I tried here and worked very well. Thanks again.

Comment: not a problem! Please accept the answer if it solved your query.